# Spring boot encoding filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I use spring boot and spring security and I need to encode requests. So I use encoding filter in spring security and add it before others filters. And it doesn't work. I have the following result:

[image]

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityJavaConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;

@Autowired
private UserDao userDao;

@Autowired
private RestAuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;

@Autowired
private AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;

@Autowired
private CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler customAuthenticationFailureHandler;

@Bean(name = "myAuthenticationManager")
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder customPasswordEncoder() {
    return new PasswordEncoder() {
        @Override
        public String encode(CharSequence rawPassword) {
            return DigestUtils.md5Hex(rawPassword.toString());
        }
        @Override
        public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword) {
            return DigestUtils.md5Hex(rawPassword.toString()).equals(encodedPassword);
        }
    };
}

@Bean
public CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter customUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter()
        throws Exception {
    CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter customUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter = new CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(userDao);
    customUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login", "POST"));
    customUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler);
    customUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(customAuthenticationFailureHandler);
    customUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
            .setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
    return customUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(customPasswordEncoder());
}


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    CharacterEncodingFilter filter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    filter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    filter.setForceEncoding(true);
    http.addFilterBefore(filter,CsrfFilter.class);
    //Implementing Token based authentication in this filter
    final TokenAuthenticationFilter tokenFilter = new TokenAuthenticationFilter(userDao);
    http.addFilterBefore(tokenFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    http.addFilterBefore(customUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(), CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    http.csrf().disable();
    http.cors();

    http.sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    http.exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/news/create").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/news/update").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/news/update/*").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/news/delete").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/**").hasAnyAuthority("USER", "ADMIN")
            .and()
            .logout();
}

//cors configuration bean
...
}
```

I've used many different ways how to solve it. But nothing works...
I can't now post this question because there is a lot of code. So sorry, but I have to write some sentences to post it)
Thanks

Comment: Spring Boot automatically adds the `CharacterEncodingFilter` as one of the first in the general filter chain. So don't try to add it again. Use the configuration instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to add encoding config in `application.properties`

as below :

```
spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
spring.http.encoding.force=true
```

See [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) for more info

Comment: Russian characters. For example: Привет, как дела

Comment: I'm using jsp, and I added <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
and     <meta charset="utf-8">

Comment: that's weird ? which ide you're using , try to check how this last saves your file encoding ? may be server jsp are saved iin other format than utf-8 ?

Comment: I'm using intellij idea. And I a little bit misunderstand what you mean)

Comment: could you please refer to file encoding setting as this article does ? https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/03/use-the-utf-8-luke-file-encodings-in-intellij-idea/

Comment: I set project encoding utf-8, global encoding and properties files too. But nothing

Comment: coud u make a sample just test it from my side :)

Comment: And one interesting thing, If i don't mistake, this encoding filter works at home, but at work, it doesn't work. Although I didn't change anything, just took it from the git. whaaaaaat?:)

Comment: I GOT ITTT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! The filter works. The database save it incorrectly........

Comment: great , the encoding DB side was the matter , post it as answer I'll voe up :)

Comment: it's better to post or edit my answer ( adding db encoding problem ) in order to help community seying your post :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187426/discussion-between-springer-f-and-daimon).